# left handed and right handed cartesian coordinates ?

Tags: vector-analysis

during my reading in Vector analysis - Edwin wilson - when i reached to the part of "unit vectors i , j , k" page 20 he stated a introduction of solid cartesian coordinates stating that regular trigonometric rules imply the counterclockwise rotation why ??
another thing that i didn't get what is he trying to explain about the symmetry and cyclic order of X Y Z X Y ?? 
i didn't get what he is trying to say from this whole part ?

link to the book 
http://archive.org/details/vectoranalysiste00gibbiala

Comment: Try a different book less than a century old. It is likely to be "smoother" in explanation.

Comment: this book actually is marvelous it explain things in deep details that i think you won't find it in any other place, i searched a lot about any kind of book that address this part that way but i didn't find any modern book do this, i didn't find except set of a very similar books that look like copying from each other

Comment: I believe you, but still it would be a good idea to consult newer books along with this one. They'll have the benefit of decades of hindsight.